# Как передать данные в файл с шаблоном

Tags: php

Каким образом можно сделать метод класса, которому можно передать 2 аргумента:

1. Массив (либо объект) - не важно.
2. Название php файла с шаблоном (например template.php)

В котором будет примерно такая реализация:

```
<?if(!empty($arResult["ITEMS"])):?>
    <ul>
        <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
            <li><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></li>
        <?endforeach;?>
    </ul>
<?endif;?>
```

Какие есть паттерны, или варианты для решения подобных задач? Не используя сторонние шаблонизаторы и др. библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Простейшая реализация без проверок:

```
function renderTemplate($templateData, $templateName) {
    ob_start();
    require $templateName;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```